# populate label with data from different ViewController

Tags: ios, global-variables

So what I have is a pop being activated that has its own ViewController and XIB file. It has a label called `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;` the issue is I am trying to call that label in the first VC (where the pop up is called) since that is where I query the database to populate the label with a name from the DB. Can I make *addressLabel global so it is recongnized in the main VC?

Here is the main VC where the pop is called

```
- (void)receivedSighting:(FYXVisit *)visit updateTime:(NSDate *)updateTime RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI;
{

    NSLog(@"Gimbal Beacon!!! %@", visit.transmitter.name);



    // this will be invoked when an authorized transmitter is sighted during an on-going visit



    [self showTransmittersView];


    //This gets the popup
    SamplePopupViewController *samplePopupViewController = [[SamplePopupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SamplePopupViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentPopupViewController:samplePopupViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"houses"];
    [query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",visit.transmitter.name]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"address: %@", [object objectForKey:@"address"]);
                NSLog(@"url:: %@", [object objectForKey:@"url"]);

                NSString *displayAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"address"]];
                NSString *displayDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"description"]];
                NSString *displayUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"url"]];

                //This is where I was getting the info to put in the pop up label
                self.addressLabel.text = displayAddress;


            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];



}
```

Comment: So why not just put the query code into the `SamplePopupViewController` `viewWillAppear` method?

Comment: @user3386109 I really didnt think of that. That worked just wasnt sure if there was another way since I have to call that method twice now. But it worked

Comment: Are you using the results of the query in both the `main VC` and the `popup VC`?